# Unable to save array with user defined indexes to localStorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have an array of objects. The array contains indexes in increment order and some other user defined indexes. For instance:

```
var myArray = [];
myArray['userIndex1'] = 'userIndex1';
myArray['userIndex2'] = 'userIndex2';
myArray[0]{
    'name' : 'Name1',
    'id' : '114'
}
myArray[1]{
    'name' : 'Name2',
    'id' : '123'
}
```

The code I am using to set it to localStorage is:

```
localStorage.setItem('mySavedItem', JSON.stringify(myArray));
```

The issue I am facing is that on retrieving it via:

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('mySavedItem'));
```

It only gives

```
myArray[0]{
    'name' : 'Name1',
    'id' : '114'
}
myArray[1]{
    'name' : 'Name2',
    'id' : '123'
}
```

As you can see the user defined indexes are not returned, or may be they were not saved on the very first hand, while doing `JSON.stringify(myArray);` So I tried keeping them into separate index. So my finally structure become:

```
var myArray = [];
myArray['userIndex']{
    'userIndex1': 'userIndex1';
    'userIndex2': 'userIndex2';
}
myArray[0]{
    'name' : 'Name1',
    'id' : '114'
}
myArray[1]{
    'name' : 'Name2',
    'id' : '123'
}
```

Though the result is still the same. It only saves/retrieve data with indexes 0 and 1. The user-defined index is not present in the result.

I can solve it by making all indexes in serial order only. Means if I make `myArray['userIndex']` to an additional element as `myArray['2']` then it can retrieve/save all data, but I am unable to understand the reason for this. Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is possible but you need to write additional code for stringifying the data and parsing it. I'd use an object instead of an array.  "user defined indexes" are regular properties of the object and the original array is stored as an array property of the object.

```
var myObj = {
  myArray: []
};
myObj['userIndex1'] = 'userIndex1';
myObj['userIndex2'] = 'userIndex2';
myObj.myArray.push({
   'name' : 'Name1',
   'id' : '114'
});
...
localStorage.setItem('mySavedItem', JSON.stringify(myObj));
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason this is happening is due to how the `JSON.stringify` method is [defined to work in the official EcmaScript 5.1 specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.12.3).

> The representation of arrays includes only the elements between zero
>   and array.length – 1 inclusive. Named properties are excluded from the
>   stringification. An array is stringified as an open left bracket, elements separated by comma, and a closing right bracket.

This means that any custom props you add to an object that passes a test for `Array.isArray(arr)` will *not* be part of the serialization. So you can add properties just fine to an object, as you have done, but they will be lost once serialized using `JSON.stringify()`.

You can override how arrays (and any object) are converted though by using a custom `toJSON` method on the array object, but you probably don't want to do this, as `JSON.parse()` will not know how to make the custom object representation an array again. Example:

```
a = [1,2,3]
a.toJSON = function(){ return "custom repr"; }
JSON.stringify(a) // "\"custom repr\""
```

If you actually want your custom indexes to survive a serialization/deserialization you need another representation that will preserve them. You *can* use an ordinary object in your case just fine, but of course, you will lose all array operations (such as `push`,`pop`, etc).

I would suggest you either store your indexes on a seperate object or by using a compound structure like suggested by the other answer:

```
myObj = {
   array: [],
   myIndex1: ...,
   myIndex2: ...
}
```

Comment: No, the reason this is happening is because array access is done by index number, they're not objects.

Comment: You are stating incorrect facts easily proven wrong by a small code snippet. You can assign values just fine to arrays, as if they were an ordinary object: `a = [1,2,3]; a.foo = 1; console.log(a.foo); // prints 1`

Comment: @ChatterOne What I say is also directly underlined by the W3 specification of EcmaScript and the JSON.stringify method. See above section in my answer where they explicityly say that named properties are excluded from the serialization form!